# Rails: add field to all forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

Is it possible to add hidden field to all form tags?
I'm trying to do it in following way:

```
module ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper

  def form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)
    html_options = html_options_for_form(url_for_options, options)
    if block_given?
      f = form_tag_in_block(html_options, &block)
    else
      f = form_tag_html(html_options)
    end
    hidden_f = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new "<input name='n' type='hidden' value='v' /><\/form>"
    f.gsub!(/<\/form>/, hidden_f)
    f
  end

end
```

But server shows the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Could not concatenate to the buffer because it is not html safe.):
```

How should i do it?

Comment: What's the problem you want to solve with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be simpler to redefine the [`extra_tags_for_form`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L735-753) method, which is used to add the `_method`, `utf8`, and `authenticity_token` hidden fields. Something like this could work:

```
module ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
  alias_method :orig_extra_tags_for_form, :extra_tags_for_form

  def extra_tags_for_form(html_options)
    orig_tags = orig_extra_tags_for_form(html_options)
    orig_tags << "<input name='n' type='hidden' value='v' /><\/form>".html_safe
  end
end
```

Since this advice involves redefining a private method, you will need to be sure to test it carefully any time you upgrade Rails.

Comment: Sorry but where do you put this file and how do you name it ?

Comment: @lepnio I put it in config/initializers/form_tag_helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
module ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
  def form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)
    html_options = html_options_for_form(url_for_options, options)
    if block_given?
      f = form_tag_in_block(html_options, &block)
    else
      f = form_tag_html(html_options)
    end
    hidden_f = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new "<input name='n' type='hidden' value='v' /><\/form>"
    f.gsub!(/<\/form>/, hidden_f)
    f.html_safe
  end
end
```

`gsub!` taints your string with HTML unsafeness.

Comment: @Tass: yeah, but that's the second thing to fix.